# How can I close a Window using the OS-X ScriptingBridge framework, from Perl?

Tags: cocoa, perl, macos, applescript, scripting-bridge

**Problem...**

Since [MacPerl is no longer supported on 64bit perl](http://www.mail-archive.com/macosx@perl.org/msg10295.html), I am trying alternative frameworks to control Terminal.app.

I am trying the [ScriptingBridge](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/SBApplication_Class/SBApplication/SBApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005075), but have run into a problem passing an enumerated string to the `closeSaving` method using the [PerlObjCBridge](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/PerlObjCBridge.3pm.html).

I want to call:

```
typedef enum {
    TerminalSaveOptionsYes = 'yes ' /* Save the file. */,
    TerminalSaveOptionsNo = 'no  '  /* Do not save the file. */,
    TerminalSaveOptionsAsk = 'ask ' /* Ask the user whether or not to save the file. */
} TerminalSaveOptions;

- (void) closeSaving:(TerminalSaveOptions)saving savingIn:(NSURL *)savingIn;  // Close a document.
```

**Attempted Solution...**

I have tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Foundation;

# Load the ScriptingBridge framework
NSBundle->bundleWithPath_('/System/Library/Frameworks/ScriptingBridge.framework')->load;
@SBApplication::ISA = qw(PerlObjCBridge);

# Set up scripting bridge for Terminal.app
my $terminal = SBApplication->applicationWithBundleIdentifier_("com.apple.terminal");

# Open a new window, get back the tab
my $tab = $terminal->doScript_in_('exec sleep 60', undef);
warn "Opened tty: ".$tab->tty->UTF8String; # Yes, it is a tab

# Now try to close it

# Simple idea
eval { $tab->closeSaving_savingIn_('no  ', undef) }; warn $@ if $@;

# Try passing a string ref
my $no = 'no  ';
eval { $tab->closeSaving_savingIn_(\$no, undef) }; warn $@ if $@;

# Ok - get a pointer to the string
my $pointer = pack("P4", $no);
eval { $tab->closeSaving_savingIn_($pointer, undef) }; warn $@ if $@;
eval { $tab->closeSaving_savingIn_(\$pointer, undef) }; warn $@ if $@;

# Try a pointer decodes as an int, like PerlObjCBridge uses
my $int_pointer = unpack("L!", $pointer);
eval { $tab->closeSaving_savingIn_($int_pointer,  undef) }; warn $@ if $@;
eval { $tab->closeSaving_savingIn_(\$int_pointer, undef) }; warn $@ if $@;

# Aaarrgghhhh....
```

As you can see, all my guesses at how to pass the enumerated string fail.

***Before you flame me...***

- I know that I could use another language (ruby, python, cocoa) to do this but that would require translating the rest of the code.
- I might be able to use [CamelBones](http://camelbones.sourceforge.net/index.html), but I don't want to assume my users have it installed.
- I could also use the NSAppleScript framework (assuming I went to the trouble of finding the Tab and Window IDs) but it seems odd to have to resort to it for just this one call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> typedef enum {
>     TerminalSaveOptionsYes = 'yes ' /* Save the file. */,
>     TerminalSaveOptionsNo = 'no  '  /* Do not save the file. */,
>     TerminalSaveOptionsAsk = 'ask ' /* Ask the user whether or not to save the file. */
> } TerminalSaveOptions;
> ```

`enum` does not name string constants; it names `int` constants. Each of these names is of an `int` value.

So, try packing as `a` or `I` instead. Or, do both: Pack as `a`, then unpack as `I` and pass that number.

Comment: Yes, that turns out to be the right direction. TerminalSaveOptions is an OSValue which is a Big-endian long. pack("N", 'no  ') works a treat!